# Trouble getting TeamCity to build F# projects

Tags: msbuild, f#, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm trying to get our build server (TeamCity 8) to build an F# project (the first any of us have ever created on my team).

When I first ran the build I got the following error:

```
The value "" of the "Project" attribute in element <Import> is invalid. Parameter "path" cannot have zero length.
```

I assume that this means that the requisite F# tools are not present on the build server. I tried to rectify this using instructions on this blog post: http://www.heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2013/3/build-fsharp-3-on-build-server-without-vs (summary: download and install VWD_FSharp.msi) but the problem persisted. I then added Condition="Exists('$(FSharpTargetsPath)')" to the Import tag in the fsproj so that it now reads:

```
<Import Project="$(FSharpTargetsPath)" Condition="Exists('$(FSharpTargetsPath)')" />
```

which I saw in another blog post, but all that's done is swapped the earlier error for a new one:

```
The target "Rebuild" does not exist in the project.
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated; I *really* don't want to install VS on the build server. The only thing about our environment that might be noteworthy is that we're on .NET 4 rather than 4.5.

Thanks

Comment: What do you see in the way of warnings? Do C# projects already work on the server?

Comment: Well - it seems as the problem is back.

I use VStudio 2017, created a console F# project, and it is exactly with the above lines. I also already installed the current FSharp_Bundle.exe.

Nevertheless, there is no v3 Framework anymore. I find the targets file under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1\Framework\v4.0

The project is targeted to 4.4.0.0 F# Runtime and .NET 4.5.1. It builds fine in studio, but it won't be built at all by MSBuild.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question Ganesh, I have since solved the problem.

So, installing the F# tools using the link in my question did work, but after some digging round in the MSBuild directories it turns out that it only installed F# v3; my projects were targeting v3.1 (the default version in VS2013).

Going into each project's settings file and retargeting for 3.0 solved the problem.